# What are folders of "Windows Kits" and "Microsoft SDK", and where's platform toolset installed?

Tags: windows, visual-c++

I'm very confused with "Microsoft SDK", "Platform toolset", "Windows kits". My computer always installs several versions of them and several build tools.
My questions are:

- Why are there so many compilers? How do I use them correctly?

```
 "%PATH_BUILDTOOL2022%\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe"
 "%PATH_BUILDTOOL2022%\bin\Hostx86\x64\cl.exe"
 "%PATH_BUILDTOOL2022%\bin\Hostx64\x86\cl.exe"
 "%PATH_BUILDTOOL2022%\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe"
```

- Where is platform toolset v143 in?
- What are in "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SDKs", and what are "Microsft SDKs"?
- What are in "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits" and what are "Windows Kits"?

  - What are in "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.1"?
  - What are in "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10"?
  - It seems "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\10" is on(depends on) "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.1", isn't it? If yes, what's the relation between them?
- What are.Net Framework SDKs? Where're they?

Know what are "Microsoft SDKs", "Windows Platform toolset" and "Windows Kits"

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "My computer always installs several versions of them", but my understanding is that:

- In Visual C++, prior to compiling one selects information that targets the executable you are creating at a certain minimum Windows configuration (Windows version, Windows Build version and Platform Toolset, among others). The settings are found in Project, [Sol'n Name] Properties, General. Prior to compiling, one also selects the active configuration of the executable: x86 for 32-bit, x64 for 64-bit.
- The Windows Version might be: 8, 10 or 11
- The Windows Build Version is a flavor of the Windows version. By right clicking "ThisPC" and then Properties, one might see that they are running OS build version 19045.2486 of Windows 10.
- The Platform Toolset refers to the version of Visual Studio one is using: v143 for VS 2022, v142 for VS 2019, v141 for VS 2017, v140 for VS 2015. FYI, one can install multiple (older) Platform Toolsets in an instance of Visual Studio
- So if one targets their application to Windows 10 SDK 10.0.19041.0, the app may not run properly on a machine that has OS build version 17xxx installed.

To your specific questions:

- There's a (cross-)compiler for every combination of target architecture and architecture that the compiler is running on.
- Platform Toolset refers to the version of Visual Studio one is using as noted above. Each one of these requires that a version of the Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) is installed on the target machine.
- The Windows Kits refer to the Windows SDK one is targeting.  You can elect which Windows SDK's you install with Visual Studio by opening Visual Studio Installer, selecting the Individual Components tab and scrolling to the bottom.
- Microsoft SDK's are a broad range of Software Development Kits that enable technologies like: Silverlight, NuGetPackages, WindowsPhone, etc...

Comment: There's a (cross-)compiler for every combination of target architecture (which you mentioned, by "configuration that one is targeting) and architecture that the compiler is running on.

Comment: Ben Voigt - Thanks for the information, I edited the response accordingly.

Comment: -  "My computer always installs several versions of them" means: I installed VS2015, and VSBuildTool2022, and some third party softwares always installed VS2012, VS2010 and serveral .Net Framework. So my computer is a mess.

Comment: @Vic Zhang - It is not uncommon to have multiple versions of VC++ Redistributable packages (or .NET Runtimes) installed on a computer. Can you clarify whether you can open and run VS2012 and VS2010, or whether you just see components of these in the Programs and Features section of Control Panel? Also, did you install Build Tools for Visual Studio 2022 so that you could build Visual Studio projects from a command-line interface? What are you trying to do with Visual Studio?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed VS2015. Then installed BuildTools 2022. I've upgraded some projects to c++20. I use QT-creator IDE as well as  vc command-line to build the projects. I have to use VS2105 to build some other projects which are still under c++11.